# How can I get a day-by-day history of any user's reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm currently working on a small project with SE data, and I can't find an API method for this, so I'm asking here.

Is there any way to get a history of any user's reputation each day?

I know this is possible because I can see the raw data by viewing the source of `http://stackexchange.com/users/{userid}?tab=reputation`, which for me looks like this (on meta):

```
[6,111,111,111,111,111,109,103,103,103,103,103,103,103,103,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,128,228,228,243,243,243,253,258,263,263,268,278,278,278,283,283,285,285,287,287,287,287,370,462,537,562,664,710,725,820,830,835,840,860,873,936,1042,1042,1107,1197,1197,1197,1212,1239,1246,1314,1447,1457,1604,1598,1601,1608,1611,1621,1642,1642,1660,1745,1790,1795,1995,2000,2055,2055,2065,2065,2065,2120,2150,2170,2170,2300,2340,2340,2340,2340,2350,2350,2350,2380,2405,2405,2450,2500,2715,2730,2900,3000,3097,3097,3097,3240,3373,3378,3388,3396,3406,3406,3416,3426,3626,3856,3895,3931,3946,3956,3991,4014,4049,4049,4059,4064,4064,4079,4079,4079,4172,4227,4237,4237,4262,4312,4322,4342,4342,4342,4359,4493,4523,4624,4624,4624,4624,4624,4624,4684,4684,4684,4827,4962,5012,5012,5012,5097,5107,5107,5107,5107,5107,5117,5142,5172,5172,5157,5167,5167,5167,5322,5322,5322,5332,5342,5342,5377,5607,5672,5672,5672,5692,5692,5692,5692,5702,5702,5707,5742,5752,5802,5812,5907,5937,5975,6032,6032,6107,6157,6290,6370,6368,6373,6428,6532,6542,6552,6552,6572,6685,6705,6725,6737,6737,6737,6735,6783,6783,6878,6880,6874,6914,6919,6954,6989,7039,7042,7062,7147,7194,7206,7293,7508,7628,7668,7743,7768,7805,7805,7843,7923,7983,7983,8071,8096,8151,8181,8186,8186,8191,8191,8236,8261,8271,8271,8354,8554,8564,8656,8826,8856,8858,8920,8925,8925,8940,8945,8955,9005,9145,9165,9325,9410,9523,9611,9694,9699,9824,9874,9934,9944,9949,9949,9949,9949,9949,10149,10189,10224,10284,10294,10294,10294,10324,10366,10366,10506,10516,10531,10531,10531,10536,10536,10566,10576,10631,10643,10641,10666,10666,10664,10669,10669,10654,10664,10664,10664,10674,10674,10674,10684,10674,10679,10709,10829,10834,10854,10854,10854,10854,10904,10904,10919,10929,10934,10934,10934,10934,10934,11099,11139,11139,11154,11154,11154,11164,11314,11459,11503,11503,11558,11686,11717,11805,11805,11815,11835,11835,11845,11855,11880,11880,12080,12100,12200,12225,12245,12282,12382,12432,12437,12502,12554,12559,12559,12624,12691,12708,12713,12718,12748,12851,12854,12852,12852,12882,12887,12894,12894,12904,13004,13014,13024,13039,13084,13184,13322,13377,13402,13422,13427,13444,13458,13541,13611,13631,13831,13869,13894,13914,13957,13962,13980,14170,14228,14428,14474,14494,14524,14569,14717,14761,14826,14825]
```

Is it possible to get this data programmatically, other than by scraping the specific user's page? Such as a data.SE query, or an API call?

I've tried the [reputation-on-users](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users) method, but then I found a problem: it doesn't show the -1 rep change from downvotes on answers, which can throw off the data. (This *is* shown, however, in the rep graph on the SE user page.)

Comment: Note that http://stackapps.com is the go-to site for API questions too.

Comment: Shouldn't you combine `/2.2/users/1223693/timeline?site=stackoverflow` and `/2.2/users/1223693/reputation?site=stackoverflow` as timeline has your downvotes?

Comment: @rene I want to get *any* user's rep history, not just mine. I'll edit to clarify

Comment: But that is your timeline which I can fetch...it might still be a bug in the api though

Comment: @rene Wait, so **you** can see my downvotes? That's supposed to be impossible...

Comment: True...I missed that...it are the downvotes you received, not the ones you voted for...

Comment: If you take the down_vote_count from the user object will that be enough to compensate?

Comment: @rene Not all downvotes are on answers.

Comment: @AaronBertrand But I *do* have access to it. Please read the question. (`http://stackexchange.com/users/{userid}?tab=reputation`)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm not sure what you're referring to. Your answer missed the point of the question - I don't care about downvotes. I care about the rep history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reconstruct the data on that page by querying [`/users/{id}/reputation-history/full`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/full-reputation-history) for a particular user, but it requires that they authorize your application to see that information first, and places the burden of aggregating the data on you.

The only other option is to scrape the user's network profile page for the preaggregated daily reputation totals, as you already mentioned.

Since this information is already available to the page though, it might make sense to [request a method be added](https://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=feature-request) to the API that will give you the reputation values within a given date range. Doesn't help with your immediate situation, but it could be of benefit in the future.