# UsersHistory Table on SEDE

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, data-explorer, beta-sites

[Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is awesome!

It's an invaluable tool to [analyze a site's activity](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph#graph),  [monitor unanswered questions and answering time](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/170999/answer-delay#graph), or just to [fetch a dataset for further analysis of activity over time](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/160515/votetype-analysis-over-time-by-month-year).

For any beta site interested in their progress, this is simply priceless.

One crucial beta-cornerstone piece of information is very hard to get from SEDE though: [user reputation history](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/164480/reputation-races#graph). This has to be computed the hard way!

However if the *Users* data had a *UsersHistory* counterpart, a query like the *reputation races* above would be much easier to deal with, and clustering users in reputation ranges and analyzing the [distribution of avid users by reputation tier](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/160371/distribution-of-avid-users-by-reputation-tier) could go against time and be correlated with other data.

Having a `UsersHistory` table with week-for-week evolution of `[Reputation]`, `[Upvotes]` and `[DownVotes]` would be very useful, and since aggregate user votes is already public information, it wouldn't scratch the anonymous-ness of votes - something like this:

```
--Id              uniqueidentifier
TimeStamp       datetime
UserId          int
Reputation      int
UpVotes         int
DownVotes       int
```

Basically a selection of columns from the `Users` table, with a `[TimeStamp]` column to identify the image.

Comment: Isn't that available on the api [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/full-reputation-history)?

Comment: @rene that only works for *your own* history, you can't analyze/monitor a site's growth that way.

Comment: Related: [How can I get a day-by-day history of any user's reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223749/237685) but uses the API.